# How API gateway is correctly used in Microservice?

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-feign, api-gateway

Suppose there are 2 backend services:

1. A product service (to get the product info),
2. An inventory service (to get the available quantity).

Additionally to that, there is a frontend web application to display product details.

All the examples I see on the internet are about the frontend and the API gateway being the same application and using Zuul just as a reverse proxy.

My understanding is API gateway should be a separate application (layer) and frontend application should use it to call backend services.

In that case what is the benefits of Zuul? why not just use feign to create a client for both services and provide an endpoint for the frontend application ?

Answer (score 2):

Feign client and Zuul are two entirely different components in Spring Cloud Netflix.

Feign Client is a glorified REST Template with additions such as Retry, Fallbacks etc.  You can think along the lines of Apache HttpClient

Zuul on the other hand is a proxy / reverse - proxy / gateway.  Typically Gateway should be a common entry point to your backend services.  It should be a separate layer which allows you to add common functionalities like Authentication, Auditing, Logging etc. As @ootero  mentioned, you can easily add Filters in Zuul to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vasanth

Comment: You are welcome Amr Khaled.  If you find any answer helpful, please vote it up.  It helps the contributor earn credits that would provide additional privileges.

Answer (score 1):

`Zuul` as a `Proxy` server not only route requests but `Zuul` filters could also be used for handling crosscutting concerns like:

- geolocation
- token decryption
- authentication
- request / response manipulation
- Traffic shaping

You mention `Feign` clients and that would work (to the best of my knowledge) with `Java`-based front-end apps, what if the front-end app is developed with `Angular` or `React`?

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot Ootero this is cleared my doubts.